# computing the percentage change in long panel dateset

Tags: python, pandas, percentage, stock

I am computing the percentage change in a panel dataset of stocks using .pct_change().

```
                     close  high     low  open     volume  t  interval  \
company date                                                             
arnc    2017-05-19  1.0900  1.09  1.0700  1.07    51450.0  0         1   
        2017-05-18  1.0700  1.12  1.0500  1.09    59094.0  0         1   
        2017-05-17  1.1200  1.15  1.1000  1.14    82340.0  0         1   
        2017-05-16  1.1500  1.18  1.1400  1.17    49186.0  0         1   
        2017-05-15  1.1700  1.18  1.1200  1.18   140224.0  0         1   
        2017-05-12  1.3000  1.65  1.1300  1.13  2016764.0  0         0   
        2017-05-11  1.1100  1.14  1.1000  1.13    11186.0  0         0   
        2017-05-10  1.1200  1.14  1.1100  1.11     7937.0  0         0   
        2017-05-09  1.1199  1.15  1.1000  1.13     4925.0  0         0   
        2017-05-08  1.1217  1.14  1.1208  1.14    16878.0  0         0   
dan     2017-05-19  1.0900  1.09  1.0700  1.07    51450.0  0         1   
        2017-05-18  1.0700  1.12  1.0500  1.09    59094.0  0         1   
        2017-05-17  1.1200  1.15  1.1000  1.14    82340.0  0         1   


df['pct_change'] = df.open.pct_change()
```

However, I find out that rather than dropping the first observation, pandas calculates the first percentage change of a company basing itself on the last observation of the previous company.

How to avoid this and have pandas drop the first ob for each company?

Answer (score 0):

It seems need:

```
df['pct_change'] = df.groupby(level=0).open.transform(lambda x: x.pct_change())

print (df)
                     close  high     low  open     volume  t  interval  \
company date                                                             
arnc    2017-05-19  1.0900  1.09  1.0700  1.07    51450.0  0         1   
        2017-05-18  1.0700  1.12  1.0500  1.09    59094.0  0         1   
        2017-05-17  1.1200  1.15  1.1000  1.14    82340.0  0         1   
        2017-05-16  1.1500  1.18  1.1400  1.17    49186.0  0         1   
        2017-05-15  1.1700  1.18  1.1200  1.18   140224.0  0         1   
        2017-05-12  1.3000  1.65  1.1300  1.13  2016764.0  0         0   
        2017-05-11  1.1100  1.14  1.1000  1.13    11186.0  0         0   
        2017-05-10  1.1200  1.14  1.1100  1.11     7937.0  0         0   
        2017-05-09  1.1199  1.15  1.1000  1.13     4925.0  0         0   
        2017-05-08  1.1217  1.14  1.1208  1.14    16878.0  0         0   
dan     2017-05-19  1.0900  1.09  1.0700  1.07    51450.0  0         1   
        2017-05-18  1.0700  1.12  1.0500  1.09    59094.0  0         1   
        2017-05-17  1.1200  1.15  1.1000  1.14    82340.0  0         1   

                    pct_change  
company date                    
arnc    2017-05-19         NaN  
        2017-05-18    0.018692  
        2017-05-17    0.045872  
        2017-05-16    0.026316  
        2017-05-15    0.008547  
        2017-05-12   -0.042373  
        2017-05-11    0.000000  
        2017-05-10   -0.017699  
        2017-05-09    0.018018  
        2017-05-08    0.008850  
dan     2017-05-19         NaN  
        2017-05-18    0.018692  
        2017-05-17    0.045872
```

Comment: Thanks! what happens when there's a weekend and there is no trading? Python just runs the pct_change on the previous datapoint (friday?). Also, I notice that instead of returning NaN it returns 0 for the first value of the company/time series, how is that possible?

Comment: Also, not sure why, but it creates a duplicate for each company-day observation

Comment: @FilippoSebastio - For first question need `df['pct_change'] = df.groupby(level=0).open.transform(lambda x: x.pct_change()).fillna(0)` and for second because same data per groups (in sample in column `open`)

Comment: Thanks Jezrael, I am not sure I understand what 'same data per group' means and how can I avoid it?

Comment: @FilippoSebastio - i think it is data dependent issue, in `open` are values `1.07, 1.09, 1.14`. Why it is not idea, maybe `arnc` and `dan` are same company maybe?

Comment: thanks! just one clarification, with your script I get an average daily return rate applied to all the companies, whereas I'd like to have it computed for each company - any chance that it is something that has to do with the lvel = 0?

Comment: @FilippoSebastio - No it is not for all companies, it is daily return for each company separately - `groupby(level=0)` means group by first level of `MultiIndex`, here `company` and for each group return `pct_change`

Comment: RIght, the problem was in the data!